How to reject non-physical solutions to the wave equation?
What approaches can be used to reject non-physical solutions to lagrangian-derived differential equations such as the wave equation?
For example, take the wave equation
$$ c^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} , $$
which has a solution of the form $f(x,t)=A\exp[i(kx+wt)]$ where
$$ \frac{w^2}{k^2} = c^2 , $$
which can form a wide variety of solutions through linear combination of $f(x,t)$ with differing (complex) values of $A$, $k$, and $w$. This leads to realizable physical solutions such as $f(x,t)=\sin (x-ct)$.
On the other hand, the solution of the form $f(x,t)=A\exp(kx+wt)$ seems equally valid according to the wave equation above, but results in a physically unrealizable situation: the flat "rope" flies upwards infinitely from the right to the left as time progresses, increasingly speeding and stretching. Intuitively, this is impossible due to conservation of energy, and one approach to establish this might be by demonstrating that the total energy $$E=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}k\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2}w\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\right)^2\right)dx$$
increases without bound.
In this case, the non-physical nature of the solution is intuitively obvious, but the approach to demonstrating this is not clear: should we employ an energy constraint as suggested, or some other constraint I am unaware of? More importantly, what can be done to reject solutions in the general case for more complex differential equations when our intuition fails us?

Hint: Think about initial & boundary + reality conditions.

@Qmechanic, off the top of my head: in terms of boundary conditions, I could make assumptions such as $f(\pm \infty, t)=0$, but this would reject solutions such as $\sin (x-ct)$ which seems undesirable, as it is a much more realistic function than $e^{(x+ct)}$; in terms of initial conditions, we could give a starting function, but the conditions on the choice of starting function seems to me to face the same obstacles as are encountered when deciding to reject an overall solution; in terms of reality conditions, I am unsure what you are alluding to.

For the exponential profile at any time, energy is already infinite, so you can't say it increases in time.

@Ján Lalinský good point

Without sufficient decay of the solution energy considerations are also always a dangerous thing on unbounded domains. In this case, the solution simply translates, so though it is infinite, one could argue it is conserved. But energy can even be brought in from infinity. There is a famous counterexample by Tychonov that does exactly this and gets a nonzero solution to the heat equation starting from zero initial data.

There is no universal rule to detect which solutions are relevant and which are not. Sometimes, there is an easy to see reason for why a solution does not apply, such as when some parameter has a value that we know does not happen (e.g. energy negative, or too high), or when it does not obey constraints set in the problem (like boundary conditions). But if there is no obvious reason to rule a solution out, then you should treat it as potentially relevant.
For example, inhomogeneous wave equation has advanced solutions, and although they are weird and not encountered often, it is not possible to exclude them as unphysical in general. In some situations, they may be needed.

I feel this answer is very much in the spirit of what I was trying to understand (with my vague question). What do you mean by "advanced solutions" to the wave equation?

@Machoo A wave equation with source (non-zero right-hand side) has many solutions, but there are two distinct groups of them. One is retarded solutions, where wave at some position and time is function of state of the source at some time in the past. The other group is advanced solutions, where the wave at some position and time is function of state of the source at some time in the future. Usually we think of waves as being due to past state of source, thus retarded, but mathematics allows advanced waves as well, and also any ratio combination of retarded and advanced wave.


For what it's worth, the general real solution to the wave equation in 1+1D is a superposition
$$ f(x,t)~=~f_L(x+ct)+f_R(x-ct) $$
of a real left- and rightmover.

To discuss which solutions are realistic/physical relevant and which are not, we need more information about the particular physical system at hand, such as, e.g., initial conditions, boundary conditions, energy available to create the wave, etc.



Yes, the question is foggy. The problem is not the wave equation (since it allows any function moving to the left and right), problem is that the initial condition might be considered unphysical. So the discussion can be done without even looking at the wave equation. So any physical initial condition probably has to be finite (if it is considered a dislocation) and if there is a represnetation of energy, than this shd also be finite (some for other physical quantities derived)

There exist a number of known physical  and mathematical constraints, which determine which solutions are valid or not. To name the major ones:

Boundary conditions. Mathematically a differential equation alone does not constitute a well-defined problem - it has to be accompanied with boundary (or initial) conditions. This is the often difference between having to use $e^{ikx - i\omega t}$ and $\sin(kx-\omega t)$ - one describes and incident or outgoing wave, with non-zero flux, while the other will have nodes, which are more appropriate, e.g., for hard wall boundary. Note that a linear combination of linearly independent solutions is also a solution for a linear equation - so the choice sometimes may be a matter of convenience.
Normalizability - wave function should satisfy normalization conditions - either on probability ($\int dx (\psi(x)|^2=1$) or on the flux. This typically rules out solutions growing exponentially at infinity.
Sinc elinear combination of solutions is also a solution, multiplying a solution by a constant is not a different solution - constants matter only as much, as they are needed to match the boundary conditions. This is particularly true for the phase of wave function, which is arbitrary (although the phase difference is meaningful.)

